# blank ("") as constant v/s direct use of blank ("")

Tags: java, string

I am using `blank value("")` at many place in my java code.

I want to know does defining `blank("") in constant` and the using that constant and `directly using blank("")` is the same thing or does it make any difference?

Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that one is more typing.

Comment: the former might also trigger some warnings about magic values, which might lead to a failed coding style report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The String literal `""` will be added to the String constants pool. So use it *directly* like this --> `""` as it will be more readable. Don't define a static constant called BLANK_VALUE=`""` and then use it. In terms of *performance*, the same instance of the String literal will be re-used, so it doesn't matter (You will have a very small overhead for declaring a static field* but that's ok)

See which code makes more sense :

```
if("".equals(myString)){ // clear and easy to understand.
//do something
}
```

OR

```
if(MyClass.BLANK_VALUE.equals(myString)){ // you will have to go back to BLANK_VALUE to check it's actual value.
//do something 
}
```

PS : Using *constants* on LHS will prevent NPEs

Comment: Thanks. will use directly like `""`.

Comment: use "".equals(myString) to prevent NPE

Comment: @abc123 - agreed.. and changed

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this. How it is more readable? You could do import static to get rid of class prefix.

Comment: @eis - The answer to this question is option based. The problem with defining constants is taht we tend to *overthink* and *overuse* them. I once had to deal with regexes like : `str.matches(SPACE+"(?="+NUMBER_CONTANT+"+"+EOS_CONSTANT+.."` you get my point?. It could have been simple : `str.matches("?=0+..)`

Comment: yeah, but in the context of this case, I don't see much difference in readability. A constant such as `EMPTY_STRING` should be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with `isEmpty()` method

```
if(myString !=null && myString.isEmpty() ){}
```

Comment: `""` is used as return blank value which is interpreted as some response from method to avoid NullPointerException. So I have asked the difference. For null and blank check I am using the code which you have suggested.